# Incorrect integer value: '' for column `myuser`.`cursantes`.`id_usuario` at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema que te permita elegir los datos de unas tablas y guardarlas en otra tabla:

Primero seleccionas de un dropdown que usuario queres elegir (tabla usuarios) despues seleccionas de otro dropdown el dato del curso (tabla cursos) todo esto tiene que guardarse en otra tabla que se llama cursantes

agregarCursante.php :

```
function agregarCursante ()
{
    $link = conectar();
    $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $id_cursada = $_POST['id_cursada'];
    $activo = $_POST['activo'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cursantes (id_usuario, id_cursada, activo ) VALUES ( '".$id_usuario."', '".$id_cursada."', '".$activo."' )";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die( mysqli_error($link) );
    return $resultado;
}
```

Formulario dde seleccion de datos:

```
<form method="post" action="agregarCursante.php">
                    
        Seleccione alumno:<br>
        <select name="cursantes" id="cursantes">

          <option disabled selected>--Seleccione alumno--</option>
            
          <?php
          $link = conectar();
          $listaCursantes = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT usuarios.id_usuario, usuarios.nomyape, usuarios.email, usuarios.id_categoria, usuarios.activo, cursantes.id_cursante, cursantes.id_cursada, cursantes.id_cursada, usuarioesc.id_escuela
          FROM usuarios
          INNER JOIN cursantes ON usuarios.id_usuario = cursantes.id_usuario
          INNER JOIN usuarioesc ON usuarios.id_usuario = usuarioesc.id_usuario 
          WHERE usuarioesc.id_escuela = '".$id_escuela."' ORDER BY usuarios.id_usuario DESC");

          while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($listaCursantes))
          {
              echo "<option value='". $data1['id_usuario'] ."'>" .$data1['nomyape'] ."</option>";
          } 
          ?>  

        </select>

        <br>Seleccione curso:<br>

        <select name="cursos" id="cursos">

          <option disabled selected>--Seleccione curso--</option>

          <?php
          $link = conectar();
          $listaCursos = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY id_curso DESC");

          while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($listaCursos))
          {
              echo "<option value='". $data2['id_curso'] ."'>" .$data2['nombre'] ."</option>";
          } 
        ?>  

        </select>

        <br>Estado:<br>

          <select name="activo" id="activo">
            <option value="1">Activo</option>
            <option value="0">Desactivado</option>
          </select>

    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Inscribir</button>
    <a href="adminCursantesEscuela.php" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg">Cancelar</a>

</form>
```

Pero el problema es que salta este mensaje de error (Y no se guarda nada):

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column
> `myuser`.`cursantes`.`id_usuario` at row 1

Nota: en la tabla de "cursantes" se encuentra una columna que se llama id_cursante y es AUTO_INCREMENT. Y la "id_usuario" que se encuentra en esta misma tabla (cursantes) se toma desde la tabla de usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en los `name` del `<select>` o en cómo recoges lo que envía el formulario:

```
$id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
$id_cursada = $_POST['id_cursada'];
```

Prueba con:

```
$id_usuario = $_POST['cursantes']*1;
$id_cursada = $_POST['cursos']*1;
```

Lo de multiplicarlo por 1 es para asegurarte de que te envían un número y no cualqueir dato raro para hacerte inyección de código.

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no usar consultas preparadas para evitar de forma efectiva la *Inyección SQL*?

Comment: @A.Cedano muestranos

Comment: @A.Cedano, ya que lo comentas, ¿cuánto de inseguro es este sistema para número enteros? ¿Qué se puede colar por ahí? Tras la multiplicación, poco debería quedar de código malicioso...

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: David la cuestión aquí es que se está ignorando una herramienta que existe para eso (para evitar la *Inyección SQL*), optando por otra que sirve para otra cosa (verificar la validez de un dato). En un código escrito con rigor habría que hacer las dos cosas: 1. Validar como entero el valor (también filtrarlo si fuese a mostrarse por pantalla) 2. Usar consultas preparadas para prevenir la *Inyección SQL*. Aunque no te lo podría probar,  nada quita que un hacker muy retorcido pueda escapar a tu validación del entero y colarte una *inyección*. Aparte de eso,  las consultas preparadas tienen ...

Comment: ... otras ventajas. Por ejemplo, son más rápidas, porque cuando las usas el SGBD establece un plan para esa consulta, y cuando la vuelves a ejecutar todo ocurre más rápido. Una consulta preparada es como ir por un camino que has transitado muchas veces, lo conoces y viajas con seguridad. Nada mejor que eso. No sé si me explico, la cuestión aquí es **usar la herramienta adecuada para cada cosa**. Puedes ser el mejor cocinero del mundo, pero tu comida no quedará nunca igual si usas productos malos o productos buenos, la diferencia se notará por los productos que hayas usado.

Comment: La verdad es que implica 3 líneas más de código, con un poco de práctica, tampoco cuesta tanto usar consultas preparadas... :) ¡Gracias!